# Trigger an HTML button click through objective-c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web, network-programming

My goal is to send an HTTP request to a web server, giving it a username and password. I got that part down, and it surprisingly worked. But, the thing is, to actually login a "login" button has to be clicked. This has completely stumped me??

```
NSLog(@"Connection started");
        NSURL *loginPage = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.A_WEBSITE.com"];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:loginPage];
        [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setPostValue:@"Username" forKey:@"ct100_plnMain_txtLogin"];
        [request setPostValue:@"Password" forKey:@"ct100_plnMain_txtPassword"];

        [request start];

        NSLog(@"it worked");
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(AttemptFail:)];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(AttemptSucceed)];



        NSError *error = [request error];
        if (!error) {
            NSString *response = [request responseString];
            NSLog(@"%@",response);
                    }

            else {
                NSLog(@"%@",[request error]);
            }
```

Does anyone know of a way I could trigger the click event on the button, given I have its ID?

Comment: Render the page in a `UIWebView`, then you execute some javascript on the page using `-[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]`...

Comment: why you want to design HTML page, just design a login screen with 2 text fields and a button, and on click of that button call this method

Answer (score 0):

Use js to send a request and verify it by:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Comment: Forgive me, I'm a noob when it comes to this whole web side of iOS. How would I go about implementing that in my code??

Comment: it is a delegate method, just set the web view's delegate = yr controller and implement this method. In this method, you need to compare the request to check if it is the string you set. if yes, call some native method. 
BTW, @Vinodh's answer looks great and complete^^

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"functionName()"];
```

write `functionName()` method in html file within `<script>` tag and perofrm action of button click